# shift space from /home to /var in centos

Tags: centos, memory

I want to increase the space of /var folder.The output of df -h is

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
    Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root   50G   33G   16G  68% /
    tmpfs                          5.8G  296K  5.8G   1% /dev/shm
    /dev/sda1                      485M  127M  334M  28% /boot
    /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_home  862G  9.3G  809G   2% /home



[root@localhost ~]# pvs
      PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
      /dev/sda2  vg_livecd lvm2 a--  931.02g    0 
    [root@localhost ~]# vgs
      VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
      vg_livecd   1   3   0 wz--n- 931.02g    0 
    [root@localhost ~]# lvs
      LV      VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
      lv_home vg_livecd -wi-ao---- 875.20g                                             
      lv_root vg_livecd -wi-ao----  50.00g                                             
      lv_swap vg_livecd -wi-ao----   5.82g
```

I tried searching it but unable to solve my problem.
Can anybody point me to the right direction.Thanks in advance

Comment: You should read on how LVM works. A good place to start: [LVM Administrator Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/)

Comment: Please add the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a script I found, and successfully used in the past, to steal space from a /tmp partition and add to other partitions.    Use the LVM Administration Guide mentioned in previous comments and adapt the following to suit your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Script to re-allocate space from tmpVol to auditVol and varVol
#
################################################################
ROOTVG=VolGroup00
TMPVOL=${ROOTVG}/tmpVol
VARVOL=${ROOTVG}/varVol
AUDVOL=${ROOTVG}/auditVol


# Verify that /tmp is now of type "tmpfs"
df -Pt tmpfs /tmp > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo "/tmp is not of type 'tmpfs'. Exiting..."
   exit
fi

# Compute blocks for re-allocation
FREEVOL=`lvdisplay ${TMPVOL} | awk '/Current LE/{print $3}'`
HALFREE=`expr ${FREEVOL} / 2`

# Nuke the old /tmp volume
lvremove -f ${TMPVOL}

# Resize the remaining logical volumes
lvresize -l +${HALFREE} ${VARVOL}
lvresize -l +${HALFREE} ${AUDVOL}

# Resize the filesystems
resize2fs /dev/${VARVOL}
resize2fs /dev/${AUDVOL}
```

Comment: This does not apply here.